# Does ElasticsearchRepository have method to get maximum value of id?if not how to write a query to fetch maximum value of id

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am writing an API to fetch maximum id. I am not sure about the default method. I tried long findMaxId but it didn't work

Comment: add code or snapshot to make it more clear.

Comment: Entity class has Id.my repository class  extends ElasticSearchRepositoty...need implement an api to get max id

Answer (score 2):

Use `findTopByOrderByIdDesc` - it will return entity with max id. You can use that.

check reference for more information - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#reference